# why doesn't resty.redis work with the ngx.timer?

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I've asked [here](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis/issues/225) but thought I'd post on SO as well:

given this code:

```lua
local redis = require('resty.redis')

local client = redis:new()
client:connect(host,port)
ngx.thread.spawn(function()
  ngx.say(ngx.time(),' ',#client:keys('*'))
end)
ngx.timer.at(2,function()
  ngx.say(ngx.time(),' ',#client:keys('*'))
end)
```

I get this error:

```
---urhcdhw2pqoz---
1611628086 5
2021/01/26 10:28:08 [error] 4902#24159: *4 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: ...local/Cellar/openresty/1.19.3.1_1/lualib/resty/redis.lua:349: bad request
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
    [C]: in function 'send'
    ...local/Cellar/openresty/1.19.3.1_1/lualib/resty/redis.lua:349: in function 'keys'
    ./src/main.lua:20: in function <./src/main.lua:19>, context: ngx.timer
```

so it seems that threads work with redis but timers don't. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your code.

1. It is not possible to pass the cosocket object between Lua handlers (*emphasis* added by me):

   > The cosocket object created by this API function has exactly the same lifetime as the Lua handler creating it. *So never pass the cosocket object to any other Lua handler (including ngx.timer callback functions)* and never share the cosocket object between different Nginx requests.

   https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxsockettcp

   In your case, the reference to the cosocket object is stored in the `client` table (`client._sock`).
2. `ngx.print`/`ngx.say` are not available in the `ngx.timer.*` context.

   https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxsay (check the **context:** section).

   You can use `ngx.log` instead (it writes to nginx log, set `error_log stderr debug;` in `nginx.conf` to print logs to stderr).

The following code works as expected:

```lua
ngx.timer.at(2, function()
  local client = redis:new()
  client:connect('127.0.0.1' ,6379)
  ngx.log(ngx.DEBUG, #client:keys('*'))
end)
```

Comment: oh this is great. thanks for your help. how can i check if an object is a cosocket or not?

Comment: The common way is to check object's metatable: https://gist.github.com/un-def/82d80ab525383cdb2ed868bb984e717a